# Use of importdata with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importdata

I’m using `importdata` to retrieve Yahoo stock information, which works fine on individual rows, but when combined with `arrayformula` to fill down the page when additional symbols are added does not initiate continue. The formula I'm using is:

```
=arrayformula(ImportData("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&CONCAT(A2:A,B2:B)&"&f=snk2l1jkm3m4"))
```

- `A2:A` contains the stock codes
- `B2:B` contains the exchange code, e.g., `.ax` for Australia

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: What do I need to change to have the 'arrayformula' fill down the sheet as I add more values in columes A and B?

Comment: @Chris: Please, create a demo spreadsheet and share it for view only with anyone with the link.

Comment: I edited out smartquotes from your formula. Was that a paste error or do you actually have them in there? That could be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work with arrayformula  - importdata, and importxml will not work it unfortunately.

Comment: A change make to Google Sheets on early weeks of 2017 makes that arrayformula now works on SPLIT

Comment: Yeah i noticed is about time.  But that still doesn't work with import data unfortunately as far as i know

Comment: I agree, arrayformula still doesn't work with import functions. By the way, I marked this [other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104701/google-sheets-how-can-i-combine-multiple-importxml-results-for-multiple-urls-in?noredirect=1&lq=1) as duplicate of this one.

Comment: wow, ok.. i thought i was doing something wrong but it's good to see it's a google sheet limitation. That's super weird though... why doesn't this work?!

Answer (score -2):

This article says that can be achieved by writing an app script that then takes the importxml xpath as array driving down the column row by row producing the results in the desired column.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147567/how-to-place-importxml-result-to-a-google-script-array

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.