# Function always parses column in first row but would like it to repeat

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, google-sheets-arrayformula, xpath

I am trying to make a function that repeats in each row of a column that fetches the URL in the first column, does an xpath query and gets an image.

Currently its all working other than the fact it always fetches the URL in A1, not the value in column A relative to the row.  The result is that each row, column B has the same image repeated (the URL in A1).

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A1:A<>"", ArrayFormula(image(importxml(INDIRECT("C[-1]", false),"//*[@id='J-dcv-image-trigger']/@src"))),""))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of importdata with arrayformula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50047/use-of-importdata-with-arrayformula)